# Why are the laws of niddah called "tohoras mishpacha" - "family purity"

Tags: words, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, niddah

Why are the laws of niddah called the laws of tohoras mishpacha/family purity? Certainly the "tohorah" part of the phrase makes sense, but why isn't it called "tohoras ishus", marriage purity, or something along those lines?

Comment: Related (not duplicate): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48966/5323

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually had a discussion about this with someone this morning!

As noted [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48974/4794), this term is a very recent innovation.  The conclusion of the person with whom I was speaking (a recognized Talmid Chochom who's name I'll leave out to preserve my own anonymity) was that it is a term that western sensitivities are more comfortable with.  "Family Purity" sounds much friendlier and more balanced than "Purity for Women." As for Family vs. Marital, I actually hear both tossed around, although admittedly Family is much more common. I don't think there was such a science to the adoption of the term.